# DbHelper cannot be applied

Tags: android, sqlite

DbHelper is the class that I am using for my database. I am trying to  instantiate it into a fragment. it says that DbHelper cannot be applied and this is in an error.

```
    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
    quesList = db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
```

That's all of the code in the fragment related to DbHelper.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the `Fragment` instance and likely your `DbHelper` requires a `Context` argument which the `Fragment` is not. In a fragment you can use `getActivity()` to get a reference to the `Activity` the fragment is attached in, and an `Activity` is-a `Context`:

```
DbHelper db = new DbHelper(getActivity());
```